# Dask Memory Error Grouping DF From Parquet Data

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, dask, dask-distributed

I created a parquet dataset by reading data into a pandas df, using `get_dummies()` on the data, and writing it to a parquet file:

```
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
encoded = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['account'])
encoded.to_parquet('encoded.parquet')
```

The pandas df was 2.7M rows and 4,000 columns. Next, I read the parquet data into a dask df and attempted to perform a groupby on it:

```
c = Client()
df = dd.read_parquet('encoded.parquet')
result = c.compute(df.groupby(df.journal_entry).max())
```

The resulting df is 600,000 rows and 4,000 columns. I have 32 GB of RAM on my machine. After a small amount of time of attempted calculation, a memory error results. This is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-083067d43616> in <module>()
----> 1 result.result()

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py in result(self, timeout)
    156                       self._result, raiseit=False, callback_timeout=timeout)
    157         if self.status == 'error':
--> 158             six.reraise(*result)
    159         elif self.status == 'cancelled':
    160             raise result

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    683             value = tp()
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value
    687 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\zict\buffer.py in __setitem__()
     80             self.fast[key] = value
     81         else:
---> 82             self.slow[key] = value
     83 
     84     def __delitem__(self, key):

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\zict\func.py in __setitem__()
     40 
     41     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
---> 42         self.d[key] = self.dump(value)
     43 
     44     def __contains__(self, key):

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py in serialize_bytelist()
    342 
    343 def serialize_bytelist(x):
--> 344     header, frames = serialize(x)
    345     frames = frame_split_size(frames)
    346     if frames:

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py in serialize()
    136         if _find_lazy_registration(name):
    137             return serialize(x)  # recurse
--> 138         header, frames = {}, [pickle.dumps(x)]
    139 
    140     return header, frames

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\pickle.py in dumps()
     49     except Exception:
     50         try:
---> 51             return cloudpickle.dumps(x, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
     52         except Exception as e:
     53             logger.info("Failed to serialize %s. Exception: %s", x, e)

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py in dumps()
    898 
    899     cp = CloudPickler(file,protocol)
--> 900     cp.dump(obj)
    901 
    902     return file.getvalue()

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py in dump()
    232         self.inject_addons()
    233         try:
--> 234             return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    235         except RuntimeError as e:
    236             if 'recursion' in e.args[0]:

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in dump()
    407         if self.proto >= 4:
    408             self.framer.start_framing()
--> 409         self.save(obj)
    410         self.write(STOP)
    411         self.framer.end_framing()

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save()
    519 
    520         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 521         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    522 
    523     def persistent_id(self, obj):

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py in save_reduce()
    784 
    785         if state is not None:
--> 786             save(state)
    787             write(pickle.BUILD)
    788 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save()
    474         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    475         if f is not None:
--> 476             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    477             return
    478 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save_dict()
    819 
    820         self.memoize(obj)
--> 821         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    822 
    823     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in _batch_setitems()
    845                 for k, v in tmp:
    846                     save(k)
--> 847                     save(v)
    848                 write(SETITEMS)
    849             elif n:

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save()
    519 
    520         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 521         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    522 
    523     def persistent_id(self, obj):

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py in save_reduce()
    784 
    785         if state is not None:
--> 786             save(state)
    787             write(pickle.BUILD)
    788 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save()
    474         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    475         if f is not None:
--> 476             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    477             return
    478 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save_tuple()
    749         write(MARK)
    750         for element in obj:
--> 751             save(element)
    752 
    753         if id(obj) in memo:

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save()
    474         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    475         if f is not None:
--> 476             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    477             return
    478 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save_list()
    779 
    780         self.memoize(obj)
--> 781         self._batch_appends(obj)
    782 
    783     dispatch[list] = save_list

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in _batch_appends()
    803                 write(MARK)
    804                 for x in tmp:
--> 805                     save(x)
    806                 write(APPENDS)
    807             elif n:

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save()
    519 
    520         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 521         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    522 
    523     def persistent_id(self, obj):

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py in save_reduce()
    784 
    785         if state is not None:
--> 786             save(state)
    787             write(pickle.BUILD)
    788 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save()
    474         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    475         if f is not None:
--> 476             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    477             return
    478 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save_tuple()
    749         write(MARK)
    750         for element in obj:
--> 751             save(element)
    752 
    753         if id(obj) in memo:

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save()
    474         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    475         if f is not None:
--> 476             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    477             return
    478 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\pickle.py in save_bytes()
    697             self.write(SHORT_BINBYTES + pack("<B", n) + obj)
    698         elif n > 0xffffffff and self.proto >= 4:
--> 699             self.write(BINBYTES8 + pack("<Q", n) + obj)
    700         else:
    701             self.write(BINBYTES + pack("<I", n) + obj)

MemoryError:
```

In addition to this method, I tried skipping the parquet steps and directly converting the pandas df to a dask df. This did not run into an immediate memory issue, but it ran for an hour with 0% completed (according to dask diagnostics). What can I do to avoid this memory error?

Comment: How big is the pandas dataframe in memory? From what you say, it sounds like you might have written the whole thing into a single partition.

Comment: How would I prevent that? Can I partition the dask dataframe after reading in the parquet data?

Comment: No, the data will all be read in one go. I will write a quick answer.

Comment: Actually, it would be useful if you were clearer about how you created the data in the first place.

Comment: I added some detail - let me know if I can answer any other questions about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask needs to be able to load whole partitions into memory, and also needs temporary memory for the group-aggregate operations. In your case, the data has been written into a single partition.

Assuming you are writing your data with `fastparquet`, you can tell pandas to [write your data](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write) into partitions:

```
encoded.to_parquet('encoded.parquet', row_group_offsets=200000)
```

with `pyarrow`, the syntax is a little more [cumbersome](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#finer-grained-reading-and-writing):

```
with pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter('encoded.parquet', 
        pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(encoded).schema) as writer:
    for i in range(0, 47000000, 200000):
        writer.write_table(pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df[i:i+200000]))
```

The right number to use will depend on the number of dask workers you have.

This is important, because your column count is rather large, and the default partitioning (in `fastparquet` - there is none at all in `pyarrow`) is done by number of rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't install fastparquet because of outdated Visual Tools...do you know how to apply that concept to pyarrow within the confines of pandas? Also, does this create separate files? Is there a better way to accomplish this without reading/writing between parquet files?

Comment: Follow the link to pyarrow, it tells you how to write partitions. I don't have any experience with it. Fastparquet installs well with conda.